# Convergence in $l^2(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: real-analysis

For $k,n\in \mathbb{N}$, define $x_n(k)=\frac{1}{k}\cos (\frac{1}{n}).$

Show that $\lbrace x_n\rbrace_{n=1}^\infty$ converges in $l^2(\mathbb{N})$.

Can anyone help me with this? I have shown that it's already in $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ but I'm having a hard time showing it converges.

Thanks. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you suspect the limit should be?

Comment: If $x_n\to x$ in $l^2(\mathbb{N})$, then $x_n(k)\to x(k)$ for each $k$. Now $\frac{1}{k}\cos(1/n)\to\frac{1}{k}$ as $n\to\infty$. So, if $x_n$ converges it would be to $(1,1/2,1/3,...)$. Now we can compute the norm of the difference $\|x_n-x\|=\sum_k\left(\frac{1}{k}\cos(1/n)-\frac{1}{k}\right)^2=4\sin^4(1/(2n))\sum_k\frac{1}{k^2}=2\frac{\pi^2}{3}\sin^4(1/(2n))\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Isn't it $\frac{1}{k}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obvious, because the $x_n$ are scalar multiples of a fixed vector. Say $x[k]=1/k$.Then $x_n=\cos(1/n)x$, hence $$||x-x_n||=|\cos(1/n)|\,||x||.$$